Power BI - Create Date table with corresponding text column
I'm trying to create a date table with a corresponding text column for each date. Like in the table below.
Date with Corresponding Text
I have the below DAX which should create a table of dates from 2018 until now but can't seem to figure out how to attach the text.
**Calendar_Table =
RETURN
ADDCOLUMNS (
CALENDAR (DATE(2018,01,01), EOMONTH(TODAY(), -1))
)**
Anyone able to help? Many Thanks
I've tried adding the following line within the ADDCOLUMNS function.
"TEXT", {"Text1", "Text2", "Text3"},
but it doesn't respond well to this.

What's the logic for the Text column based on the [Date]?

The dates are used for the x-axis in SPC charts, the text will allow me to add a slicer to these charts.

I mean what values do you want to have for each date? Usually we add columns for Year, Month, Week etc... Seems like you want something similar but what?

maybe you can try this
Table 2 = 
VAR _date=CALENDAR(date(2018,1,1),EOMONTH(TODAY(), -1))
VAR _text={"TEXT1","TEXT2","TEXT3"}
RETURN CROSSJOIN(_date,_text)

